# Finding the most similar data

Tags: statistics

Good day guys. I am working on an analysis to find the similarity between test cases of a new product and a few existing products.

**Here is the comparison between new product and existing product 1:**

```
New Product Test Cases  Existing Product 1 Test Cases   Percentage Test Case Similarity
        Detect_DUT              Detect_DUT                          100
        Power_On                Power_On                            100
        Load_MFW                Load_CFW                            95.6
    Test_Init_V_Gate        Test_Init_V_Gate                        100
    Measure_A_128K_Low      Measure_A_64K_Low                       90.8
    Measure_A_128K_High     Measure_A_64K_High                      90.8
        Power_Off               Power_Off                           100

    Similar Test Case = 7   Average = 96.74%
```

**Here is the comparison between new product and existing product 2:**

```
New Product Test Cases  Existing Product 2 Test Cases   Percentage Test Case Similarity
        Detect_DUT              Detect_DUT                              100
        Power_On                Power_On                                100
        Load_MFW                Load_MFW                                100
    Test_Init_V_Gate        Test_Init_V_Gate                            100
    Measure_A_128K_Low      Measure_A_64K_Low                           90.8
        Power_Off               Power_Off                               100

    Similar Test Case = 6   Average = 98.47%
```

Note that the **Percentage Test case Similarity** is calculated based on how similar the naming of the test registers. I have an automated script to perform that. **Average** is the average of the percentage similarity.

If you notice, existing product 1 has 7 similar test cases with the average percentage of the test cases similarity of 96.74%. Whereas fr existing product 2, it is 6 and 98.74% respectively.

My question, is there any statistical method that I can apply to above data to nail down which is the most similar product (existing 1 or existing 2) to the new product?

Need help from some mathematician here..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you really mean by "percentage test case similarity" of label $i$. Let's say that it is interpreted as the probability $p_i$ that an average customer understands the unfamiliar label, the understandings of different labels are independent, and you want to maximize the number of customers who will understand everything without calling you and asking questions. Then the probability that the customer will understand the full new labeling is the *product* of individual probabilities, not the average of them. So, to minimize the number of stupid calls, you want to choose the labeling with the highest product of the percentage points. Another interpretation or another choice objective may result in a different answer (your sample case is trivial anyway because product 2 is at least as similar to the new product as product 1 in *every* position).